# How many different versions of cover art has Frank Herbert's Dune had since 1965?

Tags: dune, cover-art

Frank Herbert's *Dune* has had more than several printings. How many different versions of cover art have been used in total, to date? Is there a source where they are all shown together?

If it is necessary, it can be restricted to printings in English, but if possible an enumeration of all distinct works of are would be ideal.

It is not necessary to list them all of course, I'm primarily interested in the number itself supported in some way. A link to a source where they can all be seen would be great!

---

On the left is the one I'd read, on the right is the 1965 first edition hard cover:

[image: paperback cover of Frank Herbert's Dune] [image: paperback cover of Frank Herbert's Dune]

[Source](https://www.pinterest.com/Takoshake/dune/) and [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Dune-Frank_Herbert_(1965)_First_edition.jpg)

Comment: I had that one on the left with the snake-sandworm too :)

Comment: I've seen publishers slap together books and unrelated cover arts. Any list we come up with will not be exhaustive.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**P.S This answer does not deserve any upvotes!** It is very deficient regarding non-English publications. Namely, in my haste, I only searched under the title "Dune" and neglected to search under the various translated titles, listed on [the ISFDB title page for the novel](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2036). **If you already upvoted, you can retract it now that I've edited my answer.**

All the information in this answer is from the [Internet Speculative Fiction Database](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/index.cgi).

On [this page](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?2036) the ISFDB displays the covers of all editions of *Dune* that it's aware of. This includes many recycled paintings, and also some plain covers with no picture.

An advanced title search with search criteria "Title is exactly dune" and "Title Type is exactly COVERART" retrieved [this list](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/adv_search_results.cgi?USE_1=title_ttype&O_1=exact&TERM_1=COVERART&C=AND&USE_2=title_title&O_2=exact&TERM_2=dune&USE_3=author_canonical&O_3=exact&TERM_3=&USE_4=title_title&O_4=exact&TERM_4=&USE_5=title_title&O_5=exact&TERM_5=&USE_6=title_title&O_6=exact&TERM_6=&ORDERBY=title_title&ACTION=query&START=0&TYPE=Title) of 23 works, which still contains a couple of duplicates (variant titles or forms of the artist's name). After eliminating duplicates I came up with a list of 20 or 21 different works of art by 18 artists, listed below. Images of #10 and #15 were not available; possibly #15 duplicates #12.

**Note** that this is mainly a list of cover art on **English-language** editions. However, since I failed to specify "Title Language is exactly English" in my search, it accidentally includes 3 non-English editions (#7, #9, #14) which bear the original title *Dune*. Many of the titles of translated editions are listed on [this ISFDB page](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2036).

1. Henrik Sahlström, date unknown [link](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1835836)
2. John Schoenherr, 1965-01-00 [link](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?345041)
3. John Schoenherr, 1965-03-00 [link](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1782873)
4. John Schoenherr, 1967-00-00 [link](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1782866)
5. Bruce Pennington, 1968-07-00 [link](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?384671)
6. Don Punchatz, 1974-08-00 [link](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2551073)
7. El Cubri, 1975-06-00 [link](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2348709)
8. Vincent Di Fate, 1975-09-00 [link](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?883114)
9. Angus McKie, 1982-10-05 [link](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1628381)
10. Frederic Marvin, 1983-11-00 [link](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1846960)
11. Bryn Barnard, 1984-04-16 [link](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?340751)
12. Gerry Grace, 1988-00-00 [link](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1922802)
13. George Steinmetz, 1990-09-00 [link](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?670193)
14. Dan Alexandru Ionescu, 1992-00-00 [link](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2729331)
15. Gerry Grace, 1999-00-00 [link](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?670197)
16. Grey Thornberry, 2001-00-00 [link](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2466010)
17. Margo Goody, 2007-08-00 [link](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1035696)
18. Sam Weber, 2015-00-00 [link](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1954370)
19. Francis O'Connell, 2015-07-16 [link](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1920928)
20. Alex Trochut, 2016-00-00 [link](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2077104)
21. Matt Griffin, 2019-10-01 [link](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2629581)

Comment: [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/work/editions/3634639-dune?page=1) also contains much of this information via its editions page. But it wont do all the deduping legwork that you've done here.

Comment: This answer is a start but it needs a lot more work which I don't feel like doing.. I've flagged for a moderator to turn it into a Communkty Wiki, in case anybody feels like turning this into a proper answer. What it's missing is the cover art for translated editions. I didn't catch any of those, except a few that kept the original title *Dune*.

Comment: Here is the Danish cover. Various editions have different fonts and layouts, but share the same cover image. I don't know who the artist is. https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/TZqWM8iPhzkJy_yzsEZxrYb_aK6xbWEH6wLfcH6uzHk0jIdGMO5wrWrsAmNK90IYqWwBLn-D--ncAnM9vtUhs4cOqfm_skITD9GH6qzzQjjAXC8

Comment: I did say explicitly "If it is necessary, it can be restricted to printings in English" in the question. Don't be so hard on yourself

Comment: https://www.amazon.co.jp/%E3%83%87%E3%83%A5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%B3-%E7%A0%82%E6%BC%A0%E3%81%AE%E7%95%B0%E7%AB%AF%E8%80%85-%E3%83%8F%E3%83%A4%E3%82%AB%E3%83%AF%E6%96%87%E5%BA%AB-SF-598/dp/4150105987/ref=rtpb_1/356-2919758-0829013?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=4150105987&pd_rd_r=46f84575-9d6a-4f7a-b623-b3d25ffeed3c&pd_rd_w=682YT&pd_rd_wg=MdLje&pf_rd_p=8cbc03a1-b057-48d5-8e15-841784c280f3&pf_rd_r=QZBP74TPJ5MB64XSDYRG&psc=1&refRID=QZBP74TPJ5MB64XSDYRG

Comment: https://www.amazon.co.jp/%E3%83%87%E3%83%A5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%B3%E7%A0%82%E4%B8%98%E3%81%AE%E5%AD%90%E4%BE%9B%E3%81%9F%E3%81%A1%E3%80%881%E3%80%89-1978%E5%B9%B4-%E3%83%8F%E3%83%A4%E3%82%AB%E3%83%AF%E6%96%87%E5%BA%AB%E2%80%95SF-%E3%83%95%E3%83%A9%E3%83%B3%E3%82%AF%E3%83%BB%E3%83%8F%E3%83%BC%E3%83%90%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88/dp/B000J8KLPC/ref=rtpb_3/356-2919758-0829013?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=B000J8KLPC&pd_rd_r=2e9bb1c9-2d79-46dc-a31d-05c2451988eb&pd_rd_w=Q7QH7&pd_rd_wg=pFM9p&pf_rd_p=8cbc03a1-b057-48d5-8e15-841784c280f3&pf_rd_r=5VHHGC6WAWE2P0ZXHN2H&psc=1&refRID=5VHHGC6WAWE2P0ZXHN2H

Comment: https://www.amazon.co.jp/%E3%83%87%E3%83%A5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%B3-%E7%A0%82%E4%B8%98%E3%81%AE%E5%A4%A7%E8%81%96%E5%A0%82%E3%80%881%E3%80%89-%E3%83%8F%E3%83%A4%E3%82%AB%E3%83%AF%E6%96%87%E5%BA%ABSF-%E3%83%95%E3%83%A9%E3%83%B3%E3%82%AF-%E3%83%8F%E3%83%BC%E3%83%90%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88/dp/4150106975/ref=rtpb_3/356-2919758-0829013?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=4150106975&pd_rd_r=0b3e8f53-f1d0-4884-9e06-4cc5c89dd3f3&pd_rd_w=E4zbe&pd_rd_wg=qqrRd&pf_rd_p=8cbc03a1-b057-48d5-8e15-841784c280f3&pf_rd_r=K7SAVE1DZBAMYBVRNXXH&psc=1&refRID=K7SAVE1DZBAMYBVRNXXH

Comment: https://www.amazon.co.jp/%E3%83%87%E3%83%A5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%B3%E7%A0%82%E6%BC%A0%E3%81%AE%E7%A5%9E%E7%9A%87%E5%B8%9D-1-%E3%83%8F%E3%83%A4%E3%82%AB%E3%83%AF%E6%96%87%E5%BA%AB-SF-543/dp/415010543X/ref=rtpb_5/356-2919758-0829013?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=415010543X&pd_rd_r=60bce618-b05d-4595-94e6-45766f393700&pd_rd_w=Nzvi7&pd_rd_wg=s2APo&pf_rd_p=8cbc03a1-b057-48d5-8e15-841784c280f3&pf_rd_r=YK5FFSG5C2B37ARDB7Y1&psc=1&refRID=YK5FFSG5C2B37ARDB7Y1

Comment: https://www.amazon.co.jp/%E3%83%87%E3%83%A5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%B3-%E7%A0%82%E3%81%AE%E6%83%91%E6%98%9F%E3%80%94%E6%96%B0%E8%A8%B3%E7%89%88%E3%80%95-%E3%83%8F%E3%83%A4%E3%82%AB%E3%83%AF%E6%96%87%E5%BA%ABSF-%E3%83%95%E3%83%A9%E3%83%B3%E3%82%AF-%E3%83%8F%E3%83%BC%E3%83%90%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88/dp/415012051X

Comment: http://tetsutaro.in.coocan.jp/Writer/H/H008.html

Comment: https://melkdo.jp/view/140913020

Comment: I'd like to mention the classic [Czech edition](https://www.databazeknih.cz/knihy/duna-duna-29765), as I really like the minimalistic yet very symbolic cover.

Comment: Upvoted for the P.S. (Pre Scriptum?). And because you can't tell me what to do. (lol)

Comment: Upvoted since you knew where to look and did so promptly. I've got the canonical Pennington one- suspect I bought my copy in about '75.

Comment: @DavidW and others who have been posting helpful comments. I don't intend to do any more work on this answer, which is now Community Wiki. Instead of posting comments, you may consider editing your findings into the answer, or alternatively starting a new answer devoted to the cover art on foreign language editions. Thank you.

Comment: The phrase "This answer does not deserve any upvotes!" itself deserves an upvote. I wish I was that humble. Not many are willing to say that...